# What does it mean for a private method to be only accessible from its own class in python?

Tags: python, static, private

I read that Private class methods can't be called from outside their class.

If I have a `Car` class with a private method `__reset_odometer()`

can I say:

```
import Car
Car turboCar = Car();
turboCar.__reset_odometer();
```

`__reset_odometer()` is defined inside the Car class.
`turboCar` is an instance of the `Car` class.  So why does calling the method
`turboCar.__reset_odometer()` result in an accesss error?

I guess 'outside the class' is a term that I am not understanding, b/c a `turboCar` to me is not outside the class `Car`

Comment: at the command line using the python interpreter (IDLE)

Comment: `Car turboCar = Car();` surely won't work. Just do `turboCar = Car()`, and please omit these ugly `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `turboCar.__reset_odometer()` will raise an exception since, even though the method is being called on a `Car` object, it is still *outside the class definition*. Think of it this way: you aren't inside the class, writing definitions of methods when you instantiate `turboCar = Car()`.

So you can still refer to `__reset_odometer` inside the class like so,

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__odometer = 88800
        self.__reset_odometer()  # <-- call double underscore function

    def __reset_odometer(self):
        self.__odometer = 0

    def read_odometer(self):
        return self.__odometer
```

And using `turboCar` works fine and the odometer has been reset,

```
>>> turboCar = Car()
>>> turboCar.read_odometer()
0
```

Of course, with Python there are no real private variables like in `C++` and the like,

```
>>> turboCar._Car__odometer = 9999
>>> turboCar.read_odometer()
9999
>>> turboCar._Car__reset_odometer()
>>> turboCar.read_odometer()
0
```

Comment: OK thank you very much!  ..."even though the method is being called on a Car object, it is still outside the class DEFINITION." Thanks this was very helpful.  Actually all of your answers have been very helpful.  Thank you I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Car(object):
    def __reset_odometer(self):
        pass
    def reset(self):
        self.__reset_odometer() # This is valid.

turbocar = Car()
turbocar.reset()
turbocar.__reset_odometer() # This is invalid. __reset_odometer is only accessible from Car methods.
```

Comment: OK, so you are saying that even though turbocar is an instance of Car, turbocar can't use Car methods?  I guess I think of the class Car and its instances (turbocar, in this case) as having access to the same methods and attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  For some reason in my mind, Classes and their instances were, for the purpose of access privileges, the same.  But now I see that private methods are typically little snippets that are used internally to support a larger method

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use __ to mark method as private. You should use it only to protect methods from overriding. To mark method as private use _

In your example, the method name is actually **turboCar._*Car*_reset_odometer** cause that's the way Python is hiding methods that start with __.

You can find more info about differences between _ and __ [here](http://igorsobreira.com/2010/09/16/difference-between-one-underline-and-two-underlines-in-python.html)